Find git commit hash for a previous run in Jenkins pipeline
I have a job in Jenkins which is designed to build multiple Docker container images along with charts. I want this job to check git tree for differences to know if new version of an image should be built.
Initially I have Jenkins build number, then I run this function with currentBuild to recursively search through previous builds.
def findBuildByNumber (build, buildNo) {
    if (build == null) {
        error "FATAL: Called with null searching for $buildNo"
    }
    if (build.number == buildNo) {
        return build
    }
    return findBuildByNumber (build.getPreviousBuild(), buildNo)
}
buildFound = findBuildByNumber(currentBuild, buildNo)

This code returns build object of previous build and now I want to know what GIT_COMMIT variable was set in it.
Both buildFound.buildVariables.GIT_COMMIT and buildFound.getBuildVariables()?.GIT_COMMIT are giving null. Calling dump() on this object gives poor output:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@5d8bc8d0 
externalizableId=devops/arc/main#125
currentBuild=false

How can I access build variables of the certain build, known by number, what was run in the same job?

proper way is just tag revision in git from which build is created. Then it is easy to find last tag matching given tag pattern git describe.

You can access parameters of completed builds (build.getAction(ParametersAction.class).getParameter('PARAM_NAME')), but not their environment variables. You can reference build.xml to see what is actually persisted to disk.
In your case you can access the scm build.getActions(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class)[0].getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String(). If you have more than one checkout you might need to select which BuildData to use instead of just [0].
Update:
I was wrong, you can access some environment variables of other builds, but only the ones you set yourself. If they are set by plugins, like GIT_COMMIT, they are not persisted. build.buildVariables is a Map, so you can look at its .keySet() method to see which environment variables are available.
